# Applying options to already loaded package

Tags: packages, package-options

Is there a way to apply some *options* to a *package* which is loaded in the *cls* file I am using? For instance, suppose that the *cls* file loads `graphicx`, and I want to apply the option `demo` to it from my *tex* file.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If a package is loaded, the option setting code in the package is already processed and gone. Thus in general you cannot change package options later.

### `\PassOptionsToPackage`

But you can specify options earlier, before loading the package. Apart from a global option (with side effects for other packages) `\PassOptionsToPackage` can be even used *before* `\documentclass`, e.g.:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{foobar}
\end{document}
```

### Package interface for loading options

Sometimes a package or class allows the setting of a subset of options  later. For example, package `hyperref` provides `\hypersetup`.
Also some options of package `graphicx` (or rather for `\includegraphics`) can be set via:

```
\setkeys{Gin}{<options>}
```

However, the option `demo` is not supported this way.

Comment: I guess there is no way of removing a package option that is set by the class (unless there is a package interface for loading options)?

Comment: @jpmath In general no.

Answer (score 23):

Use

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
```

before the line with `\documentclass`