# Documenting options of package

Tags: packages

Suppose i have a package like this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{test}[2014/08/21 Example package]

\newcommand{\bla}{}
\DeclareOption{optiona}{
    \renewcommand{\bla}{Choice A}
}

\DeclareOption{optionb}{
    \renewcommand{\bla}{Choice B}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

And i want to write a documentation, where i want to show both options like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[optionb]{test}
\begin{document}
This is the output with optiona:
\bla %prints Choice A
This is the output with optionb:
\bla%prints Choice B
\end{document}
```

How do i achieve that? i found something about keyval, but honestly, i don't get how that works. Any helpful tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't retrospectively change options for already loaded packages (see here: [Applying options to already loaded package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124049/applying-options-to-already-loaded-package)), but if you design your class file carefully then you can probably make hooks for you to latch on to in each case. Using your example:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{test}[2014/08/21 Example package]

\newcommand{\bla}{}
\newcommand{\abla}{Choice A}
\newcommand{\bbla}{Choice B}
\DeclareOption{optiona}{
    \renewcommand{\bla}{\abla}
}

\DeclareOption{optionb}{
    \renewcommand{\bla}{\bbla}
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
```

and then in your documentation, something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[optionb]{test}
\begin{document}
This is the output with optiona:
\abla %prints Choice A
This is the output with optionb:
\bbla%prints Choice B
\end{document}
```

The above is ok, but you can be more clever if you use `\if` commands, something like `\if@optiona` which is set to `true` if `optiona` is specified, and then you can build that into the definition of `\bla`. Ultimately, however, it always comes down to the same thing: making a way of specifying the two different definitions from the tex file.

Comment: Ok, hm, that's not what I hoped to hear. I thought that it was possible, because the geometry package allows to set a new geometry mid document...

Comment: That's essentially because the geometry package is written in such a way to change settings: in fact, all the keyval options you typically pass into the geometry package can be set by direct commands, too.