# Change given biblatex options after they have been initially called

Tags: biblatex

In my document I call the `biblatex` package with some given options (see MWE below).
The package including all given options (as well as multiple other packages that are not subject of my question) are called via `\input{...}` (not displayed below, as not subject of my question either) and have to be called (to have all the required packages for my thesis).

Is it possible to change the `biblatex`options afterwards (in this case change the numeric style to the APA style)?

Uncommenting the second call of `biblatex` with the other options results in the error message `Option clash for package biblatex.`

MWE:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Quellen.bib}
@book{Test:2023,
    address = {Test Adress},
    author = {Surname, Given Name},
    editor = {Test Editor},
    publisher = {Test Publisher},
    title = {This is a Test Entry},
    year = {2023},}
\end{filecontents}

%from here
\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    bibencoding=utf8,
    style=numeric,
    citestyle=numeric,
    sorting=none,
    defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{Quellen.bib}
%to here the entries can't be changed

%\usepackage[%
%   backend=biber,
%   bibencoding=utf8,
%   style=apa,
%   defernumbers=true
%]{biblatex}
    
\begin{document}

\cite{Test:2023}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Use case:
My use case would be the following: I have a collection of packages I usually use for documents I have to write. For some documents I have to write I have to change the options for biblatex, as the cite style has to be different. If it is possible, I would like to leave this collection as it currently is and change the options as asked above. If it is not possible I would copy the entire collection of packages and change the options manually where biblatex is going to be called (so exchange the commented out version of the biblatex call with the current call of it). As (per today) this would only be for one document I have to write I think the latter would be more suitable, wouldn't it?

Comment: Do you mind editing into your question a use case for this? I have been sitting here trying to work out why the options just wouldn't be loaded initially that are required. Additionally, it appears (this may be outdated however as it is from 2013) that ["If a package is loaded, the option setting code in the package is already processed and gone. Thus in general you cannot change package options later"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124052/273733). 
Maybe there will be a solution but it looks challenging.

Comment: I added the use case as requested @JamesT

Comment: Not really relevant to the question, but `style=numeric, citestyle=numeric,` is completely equivalent to `style=numeric,`. If you're compiling with LuaLaTeX (or any modern LaTeX without `inputenc` saying otherwise), UTF-8 will be assumed, so `bibencoding=utf8,` is superfluous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [Set biblatex options after loading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/264096/35864) you can use `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions` to change most `biblatex` options after loading.

The `style` option, however, cannot be set with `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions`. It needs to be set at loading time, because style code needs to be available in the preamble.

---

You could look into `\PassOptionsToPackage` ([Applying options to already loaded package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124049/35864)), but because the options of the `\usepackage`/`\RequirePackage` prevail over the options in `\PassOptionsToPackage`, you'd have to load `biblatex` without the affected options in your input file and would probably end up with a `\PassOptionsToPackage` in all your documents (not just the few that need a different `biblatex` style than your usual setup).

You could think about turning your `\input` file into a package, which could accept options (to avoid loading `biblatex` or to set specific `biblatex` options). See the small example in [How to NOT include a package in a TeX file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/424825/35864).

Or you could just not load `biblatex` in your input file, but always load it explicitly in your document. This would be my preferred method. For the most part I'm not a big fan of all-purpose `\input` files. Too often they tend to accumulate vast numbers of packages that are not needed for every document in which they are loaded (impacting performance and creating risks of incompatibilities). It is usually best to only load the packages one actually needs in each document.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will try the variant to load it without any options and pass the required options with the `\PassOptionsToPackage` later today!

Answer (score 0):

You could define a macro that will act as a case-switch driver, and set it in your main document, so that, when set to 1, it produces:

[image: option1]

and when set to 2, it produces:

[image: option2]

Here, an `\ifcase` statement is used to switch, but other methods are also possible.

MWE

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex

%\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{Quellen.bib}
@book{Test:2023,
    address = {Test Adress},
    author = {Surname, Given Name},
    editor = {Test Editor},
    publisher = {Test Publisher},
    title = {This is a Test Entry},
    year = {2023},}
\end{filecontents}




\documentclass{scrreprt}
\newcommand\mybib{2}

\ifcase\mybib \or
%from here
\usepackage[%
%    backend=biber,
%    bibencoding=utf8,
    style=numeric,
%    citestyle=numeric,
%    sorting=none,
    defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}
%to here the entries can't be changed
\or
\usepackage[%
%   backend=biber,
%   bibencoding=utf8,
   style=apa,
   defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}
\fi

    \addbibresource{Quellen.bib}

    
\begin{document}

\cite{Test:2023}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```